# Rewrite Expanding Navbar with BEM (so all the elements have the same specificity)

Tags: sass, bem

I want to rewrite this scss code to make it follow the BEM method and so that every element has the same specificity, so for it to be easily overwritten later without the !important keyword.

I got stuck on this class `.ig-snttb-navbar-toggler {...}` and here:

```
.ig-snttb-dropdown-menu__container:hover > ul,
.ig-snttb-dropdown-menu__container:focus-within > ul,
.ig-snttb-dropdown-menu__container ul:hover {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  display: block;
}
```

Is it possible to make this nav menu functional with all of the classes having the same specificity?

Here is the working example of this nav:

https://codepen.io/iuriiGav/pen/OJWdMJR

Thank you!

```
$nav-height: 100px;
$logo-font-size: 1.6rem;
$logo-font-weight: 900;
$logo-font-family: serif;
:root {
  --color-white: white;
  --color-dark: black;
}
body {
  background-color: gray;
}


// hamburger button button
.ig-snttb-navbar-toggler {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  right: 40px;
  height: 20px;
  width: 25px;
  z-index: 5;

  &:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  &:focus {
    opacity: 0.8;
  }
  &__trigger {
    display: none;

    &:checked + label {
      span {
        opacity: 0;
        top: 50%;
      }
      span:first-child {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: rotate(405deg);
      }
      span:last-child {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: rotate(-405deg);
      }
    }
    // pressed button opening the full screen nav
    &:checked ~ nav {
      min-height: 800px;
      transition-delay: 0s;
        display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
      > ul {
        visibility: visible;
        > li {
          opacity: 1;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  &__line {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -1px;
    left: 0;
    display: block;
    background: var(--color-white);
    transition: 0.5s;

    &:first-child {
      top: 3px;
    }
    &:last-child {
      top: 16px;
    }
  }
}


// navbar
.ig-snttb-nav {
  &__container {
    background: var(--color-dark);
    width: 100%;
    height: $nav-height;
    min-height: $nav-height;
    z-index: 3;
    transition: 0.5s;
    transition-delay: 0.5s;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  &__list {
    text-align: center;
    visibility: hidden;
    margin-top: calc(#{$nav-height} + 20px);
  }

  &__list-item {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: 0.5s;
    transition-delay: 0s;
    position: relative;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    padding: 0 1.5em;
  }
  &__link {
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: var(--color-white);
    font-weight: 700;
    font-family: var(--font-secondary);
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 30px;
    width: 100%;
    transition: all 0.2s ease;

  }
}


// dropdown menu
.ig-snttb-dropdown-menu {
  &__list {
    position: absolute;
    left: 100%;
    top: 5px;
    width: fit-content;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 0.2s ease;
   
  }

  &__list-item {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: 0.5s;
    transition-delay: 0s;
    font-size: 1.4rem;
  }
  &__link {
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: var(--color-white);
    font-weight: 400;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 30px;
    width: 100%;
    transition: all 0.2s ease;

  
  }
}



// responsible for dropdown menu opening

.ig-snttb-dropdown-menu__container:hover > ul,
.ig-snttb-dropdown-menu__container:focus-within > ul,
.ig-snttb-dropdown-menu__container ul:hover {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  display: block;
}
```

```
    <input class="ig-snttb-navbar-toggler__trigger" id="ig-snttb-nav-toggler" type="checkbox" data-js-trigger='snttb-navbar-toggler-checkbox' />

    <label class="ig-snttb-navbar-toggler" for="ig-snttb-nav-toggler" tabindex="0" data-js-trigger="snttb-navbar-toggler">
        <span class="ig-snttb-navbar-toggler__line"></span>
        <span class="ig-snttb-navbar-toggler__line"></span>
        <span class="ig-snttb-navbar-toggler__line"></span>
    </label>


    <nav class="ig-snttb-nav__container" data-js-trigger='snttb-navbar-container'>
      

        <ul class="ig-snttb-nav__list">
            <li class="ig-snttb-nav__list-item">
                <a href="#" class="ig-snttb-nav__link ig-snttb-nav__link">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="ig-snttb-nav__list-item">
                <a href="#" class="ig-snttb-nav__link">Biography</a>
            </li>
            <li class="ig-snttb-nav__list-item">
                <a href="#" class="ig-snttb-nav__link">Events</a>
            </li>

            <li class="menu-item-has-children ig-snttb-dropdown-menu__container ig-snttb-nav__list-item" data-js-trigger="snttb-dropdown-container">
                <a href="#" class="ig-snttb-nav__link" data-js-trigger="snttb-dropdown-toggler">Dropdown</a>
                <ul aria-label="submenu" class="ig-snttb-dropdown-menu__list  depth_0">
                    <li id="ig-menu-item-28" class="ig-snttb-nav__list-item ig-snttb-dropdown-menu__list-item">
                        <a class="ig-snttb-dropdown-menu__link" href="#">Recordings</a>
                    </li>
                    <li id="ig-menu-item-31" class="ig-snttb-nav__list-item ig-snttb-dropdown-menu__list-item">
                        <a class="ig-snttb-dropdown-menu__link" href="#">Press</a>
                    </li>
                    <li id="ig-menu-item-32" class="ig-snttb-nav__list-item ig-snttb-dropdown-menu__list-item">
                        <a class="ig-snttb-dropdown-menu__link" href="#">Videos</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="ig-snttb-nav__list-item">
                <a href="#" class="ig-snttb-nav__link">Contact</a>
            </li>
        </ul>

    </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

the above block can be written like this since your main class is `ig-snttn-drop-down-menu` and `container` is your block, so that's is been taken down. Rest you need `hover`, `focus` on `ul` so can be used together.

```
.ig-snttb-dropdown-menu {
  &__container {
    &:hover > ui,
    &:focus-witin > ul,
    ul:hover {
       visibility: visible;
        opacity: 1;
        display: block;
    }
  }
}
```